# Attempting to Apply NSMutableParagraphStyle to new NSRange Failing

Tags: cocoa, text, nslayoutmanager

All,

I'm tweaking an NSTextView to basically support insertion of boiler plate text and indenting.  I'm running into a problem where the indenting of boiler plate text is applied to non-boiler plate text after I remove the boiler plate indenting style from the edited range (i remove the style when the user hits enter).  Here's where things get weird:

With the text ruler exposed in the editor, I'm seeing behaviour that changes the indent.  After the return key is entered, I run the following code:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy]; 
[style setTabStops: [NSArray array]];
[style setHeadIndent:0];
[style setFirstLineHeadIndent:0];
NSRange effectiveRange = [textView rangeForUserTextChange];
[self applyStyleToRange:effectiveRange style:style];
[style release];
```

Initially, this works, but if I move my cursor up to the boiler-plated, indented text above this new line, the tab stop reappears and doesn't go away when I move the cursor back down to the new line the carriage return created.  It seems to me that the style of the prior paragraph is being applied to the new paragraph.

I've put a video up on the web (30 seconds 1.3 MB) that shows the problem:

http://gordonjl.com/files/indentingProblem%20-%20Computer.m4v

Also:  Yes, this is a terrible way to do this, but this is the last bug for this release and I have to ship it.  In a subsequent release I'm hoping to insert NSTextViews into a scroll area and manage it in a more explicit manner.  Until then, help!

Comment: I've made progress, but still need help!

One issue is that the above code is being run when the app is notified that a carriage return is about to happen.  the above code is then run _before_ the carriage return, I'm still in the above paragraph!

I'm executing the code now by performSelectorOnMainThread.  That helps, but still not perfect.  The problem will still happen if there is no data inserted after the carriage return (like a space char).

Is there any invisible character I can insert to fix this?

Comment: I think I know why moving the cursor up then back down applies the prior paragraph's style formatting.  My editedRange's length is zero; I'm applying the style to a zero length range, i don't think it's possible to put the cursor in a zero length range non-programmatically, hence the range will never be selected.  NEW QUESTION:  how do you remove style settings when you're at the very end of the length of the text document?  You're range length will always be zero.

Comment: Thought I would add that this issue exists in TextEdit, as well.  Hitting carriage return, removing any tabstops that were in the document, move the cursor up, then back down and type; you'll find that the tab stop has returned.  **MY HACK**--please tell me if you can think of something better.  I will insert a space ahead of the cursor so the NSRange will be selectable by mousing or arrowing around the doc, should they leave it.  My worry is that there will be a space at the end of the doc for each carriage return.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your objective but FWIW, if you are setting a paragraph attribute you might want to use rangeForUserParagraphChange. If cursor is at end of textStorage, you must set the textView's typingAttributes because it is meaningless to apply an attribute to an empty range.